# Как настроить в Ubuntu для Apache2 виртуальные каталоги?

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

Есть VPS с Ubuntu и apache2. Если заходить на сервер через броузер по ip или доменному имени (например mysite.ru), отображается умолчальная страница apache, которая живет в /var/www/html. Как и что нужно настраивать, чтобы можно было обращаться к другим сайтам на том же сервере через слеш (например misite.ru\site1, misite.ru\site2 и т.д.)?

Comment: alias — ваш [друг](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6308164/4827341)

Comment: про алиасы идея хорошая, но не получилось применить. Вот у меня есть /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, в нем подключена папка с виртуальными хостами Include vhosts/, а в той папке www-roots/mysite.ru с несколькими блоками Directory. Все работает для основного сайта. Попытался добавить как в примере "Alias /blog /var/www/blog" и блок <Directory /var/www/blog> и в соответствующую папку в var поместил index.html. Но сервер не возвращает ничего по адресу mysite.ru/blog